# Django Tutorial Part 1 'Poll' object doesn't change

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django with its tutorial -part 1 : [Write your first app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). when I want to see my Poll objects in python shell with this command `Poll.objects.all()`, I see `[<Poll: Poll object>]`, however I've changed my `models.py` and added

```
class Poll(models.Model):   
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.question  

class Choice(models.Model):    
    def __unicode__(self):       
        return self.choice
```

but I should see this:

```
[<Poll: What's up?>]
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Seems your models have not been reloaded in the shell

Comment: is that your entire `Poll` class? where is your `question = models.CharField(max_length=...)`?

Comment: here is my complete models.py : from django.db import models
import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __unicode__(self):
 return self.question

def was_published_today(self):
 return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll=models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes=models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
 return self.choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found my answer:

according to the tutorial, I added this code to my models.py :

`def was_published_today(self):

    return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()`

but when I remove these two lines, I can see "what's up?" and not `[<Poll: Poll object>]` !! I don't know why this happen exactly? but it just worked!
I'm new to django and python but i think this caused for not defining was_published_today under Poll class?! they probably just missed it...

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggling with this same problem, and have tried everything to fix it.

I restarted the shell, reloaded the sycdb, I even started over with a brand new project, but still got same problem.

I finally figured it out! its stupid and easy...

`__unicode__` **needs two underscores on each side!!** so `'_'_'unicode'_'_'`

I had `def _unicode_(self)`, when it should be `def __unicode__(self)`.

I am new to django and python, so maybe this is known to people, but it was not indicated anywhere in the tutorial and it is not obvious that there are two underscores!

Hope that helps anybody who has tried *everything*.

Comment: Finally found an answer that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem working with Windows 7, Python 3.3 and Django 1.5.1. I solved it by replacing **unicode** by **str**

For some reason my configuration does not seem to understand **unicode**

The code is then:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.question
```

and it works...

Answer (score 2):

Exit from shell and re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the Django project before changes will show up. If you have already restarted it, then check for stale .pyc files and remove them.

Comment: i removed all .pyc in my project and app, was that enough?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing fields that don't exist on the model.
Once you've defined the question field, try saving one.

```
p = Poll(question="what's up?")
p.save()
```

now run the query again :-)

Comment: i've done this before so it shows [<Poll: Poll object>]! unless it would show just []!

Comment: Your asking django to reference the instance with self.question.
the field question does not exist. So go ahead and create the field question.

Comment: @Feisal Adur: if the field didn't exist an exception would be raised. Clearly `__unicode__` doesn't get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Django specifically, but the Python shell calls `__repr__` on objects to display their value. Try implementing that method in your class and see what that results in.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'str'
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'repr'
... 
>>> A()
repr
>>> print A()
str
```