# Django Python Output

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    
class Choice(models.Model):

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Whenever I enter

```
Poll.objects.all()
```

Where Poll is the table name
it displays

```
[<Poll: Poll object>,<Poll: Poll object>]
```

but I want the output to contain the content of the table.
What should I do?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654680/django-tutorial-part-1-poll-object-doesnt-change

Answer (score 1):

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/) (which goes into much more detail on the topic of models)

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

If you want to display the content of the poll, you might want to have a method like `as_table` or something in your model that returns the appropriate HTML (or even better, uses a template tag to render a partial template.)

Assuming you defined `as_table` and have a `poll` context variable in your template, you could then render the poll content by using `{{poll.as_table}}`.

For more details on templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/

The `__unicode__` method shouldn't be used to perform complex rendering, and is mostly used to be helpful in the generated admin pages.

Comment: I tried the above step
But when I run 
python manage.py shell
It gives ERROR
IndentationError: unexpected indent (models.py, line 8)

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive. Make sure that your indents are consistent (pick tabs or x spaces, but stick to the same thing) Your `line 8` is probably missing a space or not indented properly.

Comment: The code as you posted it seems indented properly. If these are exactly your models, then line 8 looks indented properly, and I'm not sure I see why you'd get an indentation error. The only thing I can think of is that you have mixed spaces and tabulations, or one of your line is missing a space. Everything looks fine in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your code looks ok, but it is mixing TABS and SPACES at the beginning of the line. You should make that all spaces (it is now (taken from the source you cut and pasted and with TAB replaced with `^` and SPACE with `%`

```
^%%%%def __unicode__(self):
^%%%%^return self.choice_text
```

You should replace the character directly before `return self.choice_text` in **your** code with 4 spaces.

The easiest way to get rid of those is by using

```
python -m reindent your_file_name.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You must re indent the file

to Avoid this mistake

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

and know Well about python indentation

and i recommend sublime editor ( http://www.sublimetext.com/ ) with Djaneiro (Github) for proper auto suggestions